# How to reference image preloaded in PreloadJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm preloading my images using PreloadJS, and after that outputting them as children of a container within the HTML5 Canvas (none will be DOM-accessible). What I would like to know now is how I can retrieve these bitmaps later on?

```
var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(true, 'img/');
var manifest = [
    {src: 'fred.png', id: 'pri', type: 'sprite', x: 400, y: 500},
    {src: 'banana.png', id: 'door', type: 'sprite', x: 300, y: 500},
]
preload.addEventListener('progress', handleProgress);
preload.addEventListener('complete', handleComplete);
preload.addEventListener('fileload', handleFileLoad);
preload.loadManifest(manifest);

var image = [];
function handleProgress(event) {

}
function handleComplete(event) {
    for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        var item = image[i];
        bg = new createjs.Bitmap('img/'+item.src).set({
            x: item.x,
            y: item.y
        });
        world.addChild(bg);
    }
    canvas.update();    
}
function handleFileLoad(event) {
    image.push(event.item);
}
```

Things I've tried that don't work
    preload.getItem('door').visible = false;
    preload.getResult('door').visible = false;
    preload.getResult('door', true).visible = false;

I had assumed that I could reference the instances this way and alter their values. Is it something that I should add in the preload segment or am I referencing the images in a wrong way? If I do a `console.log(preload.getResult('door'))`, I get a lot of weird characters, which I think is an image file being parsed (?)

Another way could be by setting the `id` as a property in the preloading bit, so that I can later access it through `bg[0]` or `bg[1]` etc, but I suppose there must be a method already built into PreloadJS for me to do that.

```
bg = new createjs.Bitmap('img/'+item.src).set({
            x: item.x,
            y: item.y,
            id: item.id
});
```

Comment: Interesting that `preload.getResult('door')` does not work... It should return you an image reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between preloaded `Assets` and actual `createjs.Bitmaps` - once you've created a `createjs.Bitmap` it has nothing to do with the preloader any more, by using preloadJS and an id, you can simply use the id WHENEVER you want to create a new bitmap:

```
//update: as Lanny pointed out correctly, first retrieve the image:
var image = preload.getResult("pri");
var myBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);  //or use the url
// now "myBitmap" is the reference to that bitmap,
// and can be altered as you wish, alpha, visibility ect...
```

The step of creating a Bitmap for every loaded asset right away is **not** neccessary (unless you WANT to show every loaded image right away), PreloadJS will take care of all that. Also defining the x and y in the manifest will have to effect, PreloadJS is simply for loading, not for instanciating. The basic (very basic) workflow of using PreloadJS is:

1. You create a queue
2. You load the manifest
3. You wait for the Complete-event (but only to kick of your other application code)
4. You start with all your application code and use the Assets via ID to create the Bitmaps whenever you need them.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can not use an ID of a loaded image as the source for a bitmap. You can use the ID to look up the image from the LoadQueue, and pass that as the source. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 4):

@Olsn's response is mostly correct. However you must pass im an image or a path to an image to any Bitmap. The ID is only useful for looking up the result from the LoadQueue (although its not a bad idea, maybe it should work that way)

```
var image = preload.getResult("pri");
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
```

As @olsn correctly mentioned, you don't have to wait for the image to load - you can also just pass in a path, and as long as you update the stage (either in a tick, or once the preload is complete), the image will be displayed.

Comment: I accepted his answer as correct as it was the only answer given :) I had actually already figured it out a few minutes after I posted this question on my own, but I forgot I posted this question. Thanks though @Lanny :)